# How do I set a form to send the response somewhere?

Tags: php, html, forms, google-apps-script, gmail

I got a google add-on, and I am making an email, with a form, but I don't know how to send there answer to a server, or if possible, send there answer as a reply to the email, and make it to where the question is required, and also have addresses suggested while there typing

```
<input   placeholder="Address">
<br><button class="submit">Submit Address</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code and replace the someone@example.com to your email.

```html
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Address:<br>
<input type="text" name="address"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```